# Js split - как убрать тэги из строки?

Tags: javascript

Привет

Есть строка `"<dt>1</dt><dt>0001</dt><dt>Молоко</dt>"`

как задать регулярку в переменная.split('/?????/') чтобы получился массив из 3х элементов без тэгов `<dt></dt>`?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: У нас снова нашествие пытающихся распарсить HTML регулярками.

Comment: Они никогда не закончатся :)

Comment: @VladD, может составить список парсеров по языкам, да давать ссылку в качестве универсального ответа?

Comment: @klopp: Хм. А что, хорошая идея для исследования. Причём не нужно сразу писать всё, потом можно вполне ещё добавлять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var st = '<dt>1</dt><dt>0001</dt><dt>Молоко</dt>';
var rx = /<dt>([^<]+)<\/dt>/g;
var data = new Array;
while( rx.exec(st) ) data.push(RegExp.$1);
```

UPD. Дело не в регекспах. Функция `split()` разбивает строку на фрагменты, границами которых могут быть в том числе и регулярные выражения. Посмотрим на исходную строку:

```
<dt>1</dt><dt>0001</dt><dt>Молоко</dt>
```

Границами нужных нам участков будут:

1. `<dt>`
2. `</dt><dt>`
3. `</dt><dt>`
4. `</dt>`

Но никак не `<dt>([^<]+)<\/dt>`. Понятно, что можно написать регексп для охвата всех вариантов 1-4, но зачем? Естественное применение `split()` - когда границы фрагментов относительно однотипные, например:

```
var words = "foo,bar,baz".split(',');
```

Или:

```
var words = "foo; bar ,baz".split( /[\s,;]+/ );
```

В случае с примером из поста куда логичней применить поиск по шаблону `<dt>([^<]+)<\/dt>` и собрать содержимое `$1` каждого из вхождений (см. код в начале ответа).

P.S. И бонус-трек, [Pure JavaScript HTML Parser](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/)

Comment: "/<td>([^<]+)<\/td>/g" - почему регулярка в myString.split("/<td>([^<]+)<\/td>/g") не хочет работать =(


Пришлось пока что в извращенной форме сделать: split убирает `<td>`, а потом в 3 строках массива убираю `</td>` =(

Comment: > var data = new Array;

Стефан Стоянов в своей книге рекомендует использовать литералы - `var data = [];`

Comment: @FrancNet, всё-таки может не стоит искать решения наугад, а почитать описание функции split()? С чего вы решили что она будет делать то, что вы хотите? Нет, она делает ровно то, для чего предназначена, и тот изврат, который приходится применять, вполне логично из этого вытекает.

Comment: Ну в примерах я вижу что в синтаксисе String.Split(pattern); можно использовать регулярку, вот и попросил кто шарит в регулярке, как отсечь тэги. Просто для меня регулярка "кошмар", не далась с 2х подходов =(

Comment: Обновил ответ.